# How do I create a matrix in html and then parse it to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, matrix

So, I am fairly new to JavaScript and I want to create a box for the user to input matrix mxn then parse the input to JS. I know how to create row and column in html, but I have no idea with the JS.

This is what I have so far.

```html
 <div class="container">
  <div class="well well-lg">
   <h1 class="text-center">Jacobian Method</h1>
   <p>Masukkan matrik</p>
   <form id="inputField" role="form">
    <input type="text" name="field00" size="3">
    <input type="text" name="field01" size="3">
    <input type="text" name="field02" size="3">
    <input type="text" name="field03" size="3">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="field10" size="3">
    <input type="text" name="field11" size="3">
    <input type="text" name="field12" size="3">
    <input type="text" name="field13" size="3">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="field20" size="3">
    <input type="text" name="field21" size="3">
    <input type="text" name="field22" size="3">
    <input type="text" name="field23" size="3">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" onclick="calcJacobian()" value="calculate" name="calculate" class="btn btn-info">
   </form>
   <div id="resultField">
    
   </div>

  </div>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  function calcJacobian(){
   var myArr = document.forms.inputField;
   var myControls = myArr.elements['p_id'];
   for(var i =0; i<myControls.length; i++){
    var aControl = myControls[i];
    document.getElementById("resultField").append=aControl;
   }
  }
 </script>
```

Comment: *myArr* is a form, *myControls*  will be undefined since there is no control with a name of "p_id", just remove that (i.e. use `var myControls = myArr.elements;`. When the submit button is clicked, the form will submit and you'll just see the page refresh. Change the input type submit to type button.

Comment: I wrote that from seeing some tutorials on the internet and I got kind of mixed up, which is why I am so confused. Thanks for all the responses!

Comment: Did you get the answers you need?

Answer (score 0):

After a few adjustments, the code is displayed below. Note that the variable `name_value_array` holds a map which store all values from the table, having as the key the `input` name and as stored value the `input` value.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="well well-lg">
    <h1 class="text-center">Jacobian Method</h1>
    <p>Masukkan matrik</p>
    <form id="inputField" role="form">
      <input type="text" name="field00" size="3">
      <input type="text" name="field01" size="3">
      <input type="text" name="field02" size="3">
      <input type="text" name="field03" size="3">
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field10" size="3">
      <input type="text" name="field11" size="3">
      <input type="text" name="field12" size="3">
      <input type="text" name="field13" size="3">
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field20" size="3">
      <input type="text" name="field21" size="3">
      <input type="text" name="field22" size="3">
      <input type="text" name="field23" size="3">
      <br>
      <input type="button" onclick="calcJacobian()" value="calculate" name="calculate" class="btn btn-info">
    </form>
    <div id="resultField">

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calcJacobian() {
    var myArr = document.forms.inputField;
    var myControls = myArr;
    var name_value_array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < myControls.length; i++) {
      var aControl = myControls[i];

      // don't print the button value
      if (aControl.type != "button") {

        // store value in a map
        name_value_array.push(aControl.value, aControl.name);

        document.getElementById("resultField").appendChild(document.createTextNode(aControl.value + " "));
      }

    }
    // show map values as a popup
    alert(JSON.stringify(name_value_array));

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. what I don't understand is why the array is not printed. So, in your code, the 'appendChild' part prints it to screen, but it immediately disappears. Sorry, I am not familiar with that syntax.

Comment: The `appendChild` does prints in the screen but it doesn't disappear. If you execute code and press "calculate" you'll see that the appended are still there. Moreover, a popup is displayed holding the value of the `name_value_array` map.

Answer (score 0):

Try the CSS selector string for 'starts with' aka ^= to grab all values with names starting with field, perhaps make it an array so as to save the name value numbers at the same time:

```js
window.calcJacobian = function() {
  var myArr = document.querySelectorAll('input[name^="field"]')
  for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    var results = "\nfield: " + myArr[i].name.substring(5) + ", value: " + myArr[i].value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(results);
    document.querySelector('#resultField').appendChild(text);
  }
}
```

```css
#resultField {
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="well well-lg">
    <h1 class="text-center">Jacobian Method</h1>

    <p>Masukkan matrik</p>
    <form id="inputField" role="form">
      <input type="text" name="field00" size="3" />
      <input type="text" name="field01" size="3" />
      <input type="text" name="field02" size="3" />
      <input type="text" name="field03" size="3" />
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field10" size="3" />
      <input type="text" name="field11" size="3" />
      <input type="text" name="field12" size="3" />
      <input type="text" name="field13" size="3" />
      <br>
      <input type="text" name="field20" size="3" />
      <input type="text" name="field21" size="3" />
      <input type="text" name="field22" size="3" />
      <input type="text" name="field23" size="3" />
      <br>
      <input type="button" onclick="calcJacobian()" value="calculate" name="calculate" class="btn btn-info" />
    </form>
    <div id="resultField"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```